# Nib not loading views correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xib, nib

I have two nibs for a custom view, one for iPhone, one for iPad. When using an iPad, there's no problem, everything works as expected.

The issue is on the iPhone. When I go to initialize this view, it crashes because one of the subviews (subclass of `ZBarReaderView`) is actually a `UIView` upon inspection.

I compared the source code of both nibs, and they are identical aside from the iPad specific stuff.

**Interface**

```
@interface BarcodeScannerView : UIView <ZBarReaderViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ZBarReaderView *readerView;

+ (BarcodeScannerView*)scannerViewIPad:(BOOL)ipad;
-(void)start;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
+ (BarcodeScannerView*)scannerViewIPad:(BOOL)ipad {
    NSString* nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BarcodeScannerView%@", ipad ? @"" : @"_iPhone"];

    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:0];
    BarcodeScannerView *view = (BarcodeScannerView*)nibs[0];

    // this is the problem child
    view.readerView.readerDelegate = view;
    view.isIpad = YES;
    return view;
}
```

Setting a breakpoint after `view` is instantiated above, I inspect the subviews:

```
> po [view subviews]
<__NSArrayM 0x14f177f80>(
  <UIView: 0x14df391e0; frame = (17 83; 286 401); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x14dfea520>>,
  <UIImageView: 0x14df39350; frame = (37 147; 246 275); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x14df47000>>,
  <UIButton: 0x14df38d50; frame = (20 20; 48 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x14dfbdc80>>
)
```

Inspecting on the iPad, gives the same stack, except the top `UIView` is the correct `ZBarReaderView`.

I've tried restarting XCode, disconnecting the outlet and reconnecting, renaming the outlet. I've verified the nib name is correct and verified the name of the nib files. Originally, I had the logic of unpacking the nib in an `init` method instead, moving to the method shown above did not work either. Has anyone had this issue before? It just doesn't make any sense why a view that has a subclass in IB and a matching subclass in the interface completely ignores the subclass

**EDIT**
Below are images of the iPhone and iPad nib, respectively, with the view in question selected

[image: iphone]

[image: ipad]

Comment: Thanks @matt. I just did a full clean, removed derived data, and everything else from your post and it's still misbehaving. That'd be super helpful! I have an old private repo on github that I just need to update with it. What's your github handle?

Comment: @matt I got 5 free ones a while ago with a student code! I started a chat with you on SO, not sure if it pinged you